# Method to 'rock' a value back and forth

Tags: c#, xna

I'm working on a small game, I have objects which I want to elevate up and down. Object moves to max value of Y -> Object moves to min value of Y -> Repeat. I have a rough idea of how to do this, I would put this in a timer/my update method.

```
if(Y >= max)
{
    direction = "down";
}
if(y =< min)
{
    direction = "up";
}

if(direction == "up") Y -= speed;
if(direction == "down") Y += speed;
```

(Could also use a bool ofcourse but, for the sake of implicity)

But it feels like I'm just re-inventing the wheel, is there by any chance a built in method/math function to do this automatically? eg. SomeFunction(min, max, increment).
I'm using the XNA framework, so functions built into that are ofcourse welcome as well.

Comment: Is the rate of going up/down supposed to be linear? If it isn't, then it looks like you could use a sine function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget having a separate `direction` flag.

Just use a negative speed for "up" to simplify the code:

```
if ((Y >= max) || (Y <= min)) // Hit an edge?
   speed = -speed;            // Reverse direction.

Y += speed;
```

Comment: Very clean and subtle, I'll just turn this into a method. Thanks! :)